# RDP from Windows 10 to XRDP on 17.0.4 = RDP crash?

Tags: server, remote-desktop, 17.04, xrdp

So I just installed the latest version of XRDP on my ubuntu 17.04 Server VM. When I try and use RDP from Windows 10 and use the Xorg session, after I log in RDP crashes. I don't see any errors in the xrdp error log in /var/log, I have the port open in ufw, and it's on my local network.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in to the machine locally while trying to connect remotely? It seems like in the xrdp setup in 17.04 you can no longer do that.